# remove an access from a specific person to a specific file or folder of Sharepoint et Onedrive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, access, script

I am actually working on a script that should remove access from a specific person to a specific file or folder.
We can share files to person from outside our organisation using Onedrive and Sharepoint. Therefore, we need to be able to remove the access from this guest. I need a script that when i give an account and a file URL, the script will remove the acces from this person to this specific file

I don't have a script to show you because i don't even know where to start !

I need your help pliz !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell scripts:

**Remove User from folder permissions using PowerShell:**

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Remove-SPOUserPermissionsFromList()
{
  param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $FolderURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserAccount
    )

    Try {
        #Get credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
        $Web = $Ctx.web

        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderURL)
        $Ctx.Load($Folder)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Break Permission inheritence - Keep all existing list permissions & Don't keep Item level permissions
        $Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($True,$False)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."

        #Get the SharePoint User object from the site
        $User = $Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
        $Ctx.load($User)

        #Get permissions assigned to the folder
        $Ctx.Load($Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Check if the user has permission on the list
        [Bool]$UserFound = $False
        ForEach($RoleAssignment in $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments)
        {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #remove user permission from folder
            If($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $User.LoginName)
            {
                $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal($User).DeleteObject()
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                $UserFound = $True
                Write-host "User Permissions Removed from the List Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 
            }
        }
        #If user doesn't exist in list permissions
        If($UserFound -eq $False) { Write-host "User Not found in List Permissions!" -ForegroundColor Red}
    }
    Catch {
       write-host -f Red "Error Removing permissions from the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Config Variables
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
$FolderURL="/Project Docs/Active"
$UserAccount="Salaudeen@Crescent.com"

#Call the function to remove user permissions from a list
Remove-SPOUserPermissionsFromList -SiteURL $SiteURL -FolderURL $FolderURL -UserAccount $UserAccount
```

**Remove Group from Folder Permissions using PowerShell**

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Remove-SPOGroupPermissionsFromList()
{
  param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $FolderURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $GroupName
    )

    Try {
        #Get credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
        $Web = $Ctx.web

        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderURL)
        $Ctx.Load($Folder)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Break Permission inheritence - Keep all existing list permissions & Don't keep Item level permissions
        $Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($True,$False)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."

        #Get the SharePoint Site Group object
        $Group =$Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName)
        $Ctx.load($Group)

        #Get permissions assigned to the folder
        $Ctx.Load($Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Check if the Group has permission on the list
        [Bool]$GroupFound = $False
        ForEach($RoleAssignment in $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments)
        {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #remove Group permission from folder
            If($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $Group.LoginName)
            {
                $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal($Group).DeleteObject()
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                $GroupFound = $True
                Write-host "Group Permissions Removed from the List Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 
            }
        }
        #If Group doesn't exist in list permissions
        If($GroupFound -eq $False) { Write-host "Group Not found in List Permissions!" -ForegroundColor Red}
    }
    Catch {
       write-host -f Red "Error Removing Group permissions from the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Config Variables
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
$FolderURL="/Project Docs/Active"
$GroupName="Team Site Visitors"

#Call the function to remove Group permissions from a list
Remove-SPOGroupPermissionsFromList -SiteURL $SiteURL -FolderURL $FolderURL -GroupName $GroupName
```

Source:

[SharePoint Online: Remove User or Group from Folder Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-remove-user-group-from-folder-permissions-using-powershell.html)

**Or**

You can use the below SPO command:

```
$user = Get-SPOExternalUser -Filter someone@example.com
Remove-SPOExternalUser -UniqueIDs @($user.UniqueId)
```

Description about **Remove-SPOExternalUser**:

The Remove-SPOExternalUser cmdlet permanently removes a collection of external users from the tenancy's folder.

For details on this refer to the below MSDN article:

[Remove-SPOExternalUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spoexternaluser?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Or** even, if it is just concerned about the sharing the link to the external user - you can configure the link-sharing setting from the admin center site - using that we can define the shared link how many days the external user can access - after that period the link will be invalid.

Example:

Go to SharePoint online admin center -> **Policy** -> **Sharing**

[image: External link sharing in SharePoint Online]